# trying to filter brand but brand_id shows undefined

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to filter brand using toggle sidebar but brandid shows undefined

**Views**

```
@foreach($brands as $brand)
    <a onclick="brandfilter();" href="javascript:void(0)" >{{$brand}}</a>=
@endforeach
```

**jQuery Ajax:**

```
function brandfilter(brand_id, url = null)
{

    if($('div#product_list_body').length == 0) {
        return false;
    }
    if (url == null) {
        url = '/sells/pos/get-product-suggestion';
    }

    $('#suggestion_page_loader').fadeIn(700);

    var page = $('input#suggestion_page').val();
    if (page == 1) {
        $('div#product_list_body').html('');
    }

    if ($('div#product_list_body').find('input#no_products_found').length > 0) {
        $('#suggestion_page_loader').fadeOut(700);
        return false;
    }

    $.ajax({
        method: 'GET',
        url: url,
        data: {
            brand_id: brand_id,
            page: page
        },
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(result) {
            $('div#product_list_body').append(result);
            $('#wrapper-right').fadeOut(700);
        },
    });   
  }
```

**Controller**

```
$brands = (request()->session()->get('business.enable_brand') == 1) ? Brands::where('business_id', $business_id)
                ->pluck('name', 'id')
                ->prepend(__('lang_v1.all_brands'), 'all') : false;
```

dumb view
all" => "All Brands"
    10 => "Meem"
    11 => "Pickles Achaar"
    12 => "Cookies by Abeer"

Comment: where you define your brand_id

Comment: controller $brands = (request()->session()->get('business.enable_brand') == 1) ? Brands::where('business_id', $business_id) ->pluck('name', 'id') ->prepend(__('lang_v1.all_brands'), 'all') : false;

Comment: you created function `brandfilter` in jquery and passing brand_id. but you calling that function in view onClick on link `brandfilter()` but here you are not passing brand_id. Then how will this work?

Comment: Pass parameter in brandfilter function like this    <a onclick="brandfilter({{$brand_id}});" href="javascript:void(0)" >{{$brand}}</a>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please modify your view file code as follow:

```
@foreach($brands as $brand_id => $brand)
    <a onclick="brandfilter({{$brand_id}});" href="javascript:void(0)" >{{$brand}}</a>
@endforeach
```

Comment: What are you getting in $brand in view file? Please print $brand array.

Comment: $brand array has brand name like full list of brand names

Comment: Please copy dump($brands) here.

Comment: <span class=sf-dump-key>all</span>" => "<span class=sf-dump-str title="10 characters">All Brands</span>"
    <span class=sf-dump-key>10</span> => "<span class=sf-dump-str title="4 characters">Meem</span>"
    <span class=sf-dump-key>11</span> => "<span class=sf-dump-str title="14 characters">Pickles Achaar</span>"
    <span class=sf-dump-key>12</span> => "<span class=sf-dump-str title="16 characters">Cookies by Abeer</span>"

Comment: I have edited my answer please try that code in view file.